# ptheard not working on Ubuntu with matrix

Tags: c, linux, bash, multithreading, pthreads

this code works correctly on Windows, but does not give results on Ubuntu. What am I supposed to do about it ?

By the way, I use Ubuntu through a virtual machine, but I don't think it has anything to do with it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUM_THREADS    4
#define MATRIX_SIZE 4

int  matrixA[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
int  matrixB[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
int  matrixSerial[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]={0};
int  matrixParallel[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]={0};
//Randomize matrix A and B
void randomizeMatrixAandMatrixB()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<MATRIX_SIZE;i++)
        for(j=0; j<MATRIX_SIZE;j++)
        {
            matrixA[i][j]=rand() % 10;
            matrixB[i][j]=rand() % 10;
        }   
}
//this void is Matrix2D
void printMatrix2D(int mat2D[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mat2D[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    printf("\n");   
}

//I created this here serailMatrix
void serialMatrixMultiplication()
{   
    int row, column,i;
    for (row = 0; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++)
        for (column = 0; column < MATRIX_SIZE; column++)
            for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
                matrixSerial[row][column] += matrixA[row][i] * matrixB[i][column];

}

//int step for multiplyMatrix
int step_i = 0;
void *multiplyMatrix(void*arg )
{   
    int core=step_i++;
    int row, column,i;
    for (row = core * MATRIX_SIZE / 4; row < (core + 1) * MATRIX_SIZE / 4; row++){
    
        for (column = 0; column < MATRIX_SIZE; column++){
            for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
                        matrixParallel[row][column] += matrixA[row][i] * matrixB[i][column];
            }
        }
    }
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

//void paraleleling 
void parallelMatrixMultiplication()
{
    pthread_t *thread;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        int* p;
        thread=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        pthread_create(thread, NULL, multiplyMatrix, (void*)(p));
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    //Randomize
    randomizeMatrixAandMatrixB();
    printf("Matrix A\n");
    printMatrix2D(matrixA);
    printf("Matrix B\n");
    printMatrix2D(matrixB);
    
    
    //Serial Matrix Multiplication
    serialMatrixMultiplication();
    printf("Serial Multiplication\n");
    printMatrix2D(matrixSerial);
    
    //Parallel Matrix Multiplication
    parallelMatrixMultiplication();
    printMatrix2D(matrixParallel);
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to run these codes in the virtual machine? Where is my mistake in the line of code? Since it works fine on Windows, not on linux, it shows the remaining values as 0 from the first line. For example, when we divide it into 4 threads on a 4x4 matrix, the first row looks like this starting from 0. I guess it's not running threads

```
For Example:
Serial Multiplaction
144 255 1 2
15 18 5 4
125 14 52 46
14 5 1 3


0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Clearly a race condition. Add `sleep(1)` after `parallelMatrixMultiplication();` and it works fine (not saying that's a fix though).

Comment: `int core=step_i++;` The code makes no attempt at mutual exclusion nor synchronisation. For example, more than one thread can get the same value for `core` - the code needs to use mutual exclusion (e.g. with mutex) to ensure that operation is done atomically with respect to each thread. There may be other places where that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were lucky it works on windows.

What is missing in you code is synchronisation.

You must wait for threads to finish before displaying the result. You can easily do this with `pthread_join`

```
//void paraleleling  
void parallelMatrixMultiplication()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int params[NUM_THREADS];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        params[i] = i;
        pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, multiplyMatrix, &params[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also changed the argument given to `multiplyMatrix` to avoid using `step_i`: In main thread, an array containing the parameters is prepared.

```
//int step for multiplyMatrix
void *multiplyMatrix(void*arg )
{   
    int core=*(int*)arg;
    int row, column,i;
    for (row = core * MATRIX_SIZE / 4; row < (core + 1) * MATRIX_SIZE / 4; row++){
    
        for (column = 0; column < MATRIX_SIZE; column++){
            for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
                        matrixParallel[row][column] += matrixA[row][i] * matrixB[i][column];
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

---

One last thing: if two different threads could modify the same cell in `matrixParallel`, it would be a good idea to add some mutex.

Comment: I solved my problem with this code thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. `parallelMatrixMultiplication()` kicks off the processing threads then goes straight into `printMatrix2D()`. You are not waiting for the threads to finish.
2. You have a memory leak because you are reusing the `thread` variable in `parallelMatrixMultiplication()`. You call `malloc()` but not `free()`.